# Border not working for "table" of Divs

Tags: css, html

I'm Trying to make a printer friendly page using  tags and basic borders. My code as of this moment is...

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
</div>
```

The only CSS applied is inline. This works the way I want it to in IE...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/abjdX.png

In Chrome, the contents of the "table" appear below the border, like so...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYNnk.png

Any and all help is greatly appreciated,
Rock

p.s. Here is a JFiddle for funsies

Comment: Hmmm...did you clear your floats?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rYj7M/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the quick answer. I'll be sure to mark as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to clear your floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/avAv5/

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `overflow: hidden`

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7S9h/

Another solution would be to clear your floats:

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7S9h/1/

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
overflow: auto
```

to the surrounding div

Answer (score 0):

It is so, because of floating children.

Try like this:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; ">Text</div>
    <div style="width: 34%; float: left; ">Text</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgqkw/